# Conditional summarize across a row

Tags: r

I am trying to summarize across columns where `NA` is treated as `0` so long as at least one column has a numerical value, but return `NA` if both are `NA`.

I'm trying to call `rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)` but have it return `NA` when all rows are `NA`. For example,

```
# Data example
a <- c(5, NA, NA)
b <- c(6, 6, NA)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

# RowSums
df$c <- rowSums(df[,c("a","b")], na.rm=T)
head(df)
```

Gives me:

```
   a  b  c
1  5  6 11
2 NA  6  6
3 NA NA  0
```

What I really want is:

```
   a  b  c
1  5  6 11
2 NA  6  6
3 NA NA  NA
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Making things c is generally speaking a bad idea: e.g. `c <- 5; foo<- c` it's unclear in this code if foo is the function c() or 5

Comment: That's a good point, c is stylistically not ideal, but this is just example data. However, careful reading of the code would clear up any confusion one may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if all values are NA:

```
df$c <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), NA, rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE))
df
#    a  b  c
# 1  5  6 11
# 2 NA  6  6
# 3 NA NA NA
```

---

**Edit:** to sum specified subset of columns:

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
df$c <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[, cols ])) == length(cols), NA, rowSums(df[, cols ], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've updated the code to be able to accept specific column names as listed above: `df$c <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[,c("a","b")])) == ncol(df[,c("a","b")]), NA, rowSums(df[,c("a","b")], na.rm = TRUE))`. It might be worth adding to your answer.

Comment: @jikac edited, added solution to sum specified columns.

Comment: Why using `ifelse`, `replace(rowSums(df[, c("a", "b")], na.rm=TRUE), rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), NA)` should be much faster.

Comment: @jay.sf it is just a choice, I never use replace, nothing against it,  it just never comes to my mind. Feel free to edit, or post as new answer, and benchmark.

Comment: @zx8754 Done. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492774/6574038). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options using `replace`.

```
> replace(rowSums(df[, c("a", "b")], na.rm=TRUE), rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), NA)
[1] 11  6 NA
> replace(matrixStats::rowSums2(as.matrix(df[, c("a", "b")]), na.rm=TRUE), matrixStats::rowSums2(is.na(df)) == ncol(df), NA)
[1] 11  6 NA
> replace(matrixStats::rowSums2(as.matrix(df[, c("a", "b")]), na.rm=TRUE), matrixStats::rowAlls(is.na(df)), NA)
[1] 11  6 NA
```

### benchmark

```
set.seed(42)
df_l <- df[sample.int(nrow(df), 1e6, replace=TRUE), ]
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ifelse=ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df_l)) == ncol(df), NA, rowSums(df_l, na.rm=TRUE)),
                               rowSums=replace(rowSums(df_l[, c("a", "b")], na.rm=TRUE), rowSums(is.na(df_l)) == ncol(df), NA),
                               rowSums2=replace(matrixStats::rowSums2(as.matrix(df_l[, c("a", "b")]), na.rm=TRUE), matrixStats::rowSums2(is.na(df_l)) == ncol(df), NA),
                               rowAlls=replace(matrixStats::rowSums2(as.matrix(df_l[, c("a", "b")]), na.rm=TRUE), matrixStats::rowAlls(is.na(df_l)), NA),
                               check='identical',
                               times=100)

$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
   ifelse 160.85751 206.74376 244.02137 228.24369 267.05320 482.0305   100 a  
  rowSums  76.93272  82.05174 105.14587 109.61339 119.81780 145.3499   100  b 
 rowSums2  51.18624  56.61679  79.84028  84.35393  91.87599 171.9896   100   c
  rowAlls  50.84960  59.34641  79.95117  82.42595  88.28095 170.9503   100   c
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(5, NA, NA), b = c(6, 6, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I will never remember the meaning of cld, obviously "rowsums" mean runtime is 2x faster than "ifelse", but "ifelse" gets the "a" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯